# Laurent series of $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ about $x=\infty$/MacLaurin series of $\left(1+x\right)^\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, laurent-series

For those who do not know, a Laurent series is like a Taylor series, but with terms that can have exponents of negative degree. I was wondering how I can find the Laurent series of $$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$ about $x=\infty$. 
Entering into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laurent+series+of+%281%2B1%2Fx%29%5Ex+around+x+%3D+infinity), we get that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e-\frac{e}{2x}+\frac{11e}{24x^2}+... = e\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{-n}$$ where the $a_n$ are very likely all rational numbers. I want to find the values of $a_n$.

To hopefully make this simpler, this is equivalent to finding the values of $a_n$ in the MacLaurin series of $$(1+x)^\frac{1}{x} = e-\frac{e}{2}x+\frac{11e}{24}x^2+... = e\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$

I honestly do not know what to do from here, as taking the $n$th derivative just makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=-\frac 1t$ and consider the series expansion of 
$$\frac 1 e (1-t)^{-1/t}$$ built at $t=0$. It will write
$$\frac 1 e (1-t)^{-1/t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{b_n} t^n$$ for which the first terms are

- for $a_n$

$$\{1,1,11,7,2447,959,238043,67223,559440199,123377159,29128857391\}$$

- for $b_n$

$$\{1,2,24,16,5760,2304,580608,165888,1393459200,309657600,73574645760\}$$

These correspond respectively to sequences [$A055505$](http://oeis.org/search?q=11%2C7%2C2447&sort=&language=&go=Search) and [$A055535$](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+24%2C+16%2C+5760&sort=&language=&go=Search) on $OEIS$.

Looking at the comments in the linked $OEIS$ pages, for the series expansion of
$$ (1+t)^{1/t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {c_n} t^n$$ we have
$$\color{blue}{c_n=\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{ \Gamma (n+1-k,-1)}{ (n+k)! \,(n-k)!}\,S_{k+n}^{(k)}}$$ where appear Stirling numbers of the first kind.

These are your coefficients.

Comment: Can you include the derivation of this formula? I didn't see anything in the linked OEIS pages about this.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated; Look at Vladimir Reshetnikov's comments in the Mathematica part for the first sequence.

Comment: That just gives an alternate formula.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated  It is the same formula.

Comment: Ok, but how was the formula derived?

Answer (score 1):

Note:
Nothing original here.

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\\
&=\exp(x\ln(1+\frac1{x}))\\
&=\exp(x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{nx^n})\\
&=\exp(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{nx^{n-1}})\\
&=\exp(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)x^{n}})\\
&=\exp(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)x^{n}})\\
&=e\exp(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)x^{n}})\\
\end{array}
$

At this point,
you want to get
$\exp(g(x))$
for a power series
$g(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_nx^n
$.

Here is a standard way
to do this:

Let
$h(x) = \exp(g(x))
$
where
$g(0) = 0$.

We will get
a recurrence
for the coefficients of $h(x)$.

Then
$h'(x)
=(\exp(g(x)))'
=g'(x)\exp(g(x))
=g'(x) h(x)
$.

Let
$h(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} h_n x^n
$
and
$g(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g_n x^n
$
with
$g_0=0$.

Then
$h'(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nh_n x^{n-1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)h_{n+1} x^{n}
$
and
$g'(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ng_n x^{n-1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)g_{n+1} x^{n}
$.

Therefore,
from
$h'(x)
=g'(x) h(x)
$
we have

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)h_{n+1} x^{n}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)g_{n+1} x^{n}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} h_m x^m\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (n+1)g_{n+1}h_m x^{n+m}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
\sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1)g_{k+1}h_{n-k}\\
\text{so}\\
 (n+1)h_{n+1}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1)g_{k+1}h_{n-k}\\
\text{or}\\
h_{n+1}
&=\dfrac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1)g_{k+1}h_{n-k}\\
&=\dfrac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k+1)g_{n-k+1}h_{k}\\
\end{array}
$

To initialize,
$h_0
=h(0)
=\exp(g(0))
=\exp(g(0))
=1
$.

We have
$g_n
=(0, -\frac12, \frac13,
-\frac14, ...
)$,
so

$n=0:
h_1
=g_1h_0
=-\dfrac12
$.

$n=1:
h_2
=\dfrac1{2}(2g_2h_0+g_1h_1)
=\dfrac12(2(\frac13)-\frac12(-\frac12))
=\dfrac12(\frac23+\frac14)
=\dfrac{11}{24}
$.

$n=2:
h_3
=\dfrac1{3}(3g_3h_0+2g_2h_1+g_1h_2)
=\dfrac1{3}(3(-\frac14)+2(\frac13)(-\frac12)+(-\frac12)\frac{11}{24})\\
=\dfrac1{3}(-\frac34-\frac13-\frac{11}{48})
=\dfrac1{3}\dfrac{-3\cdot 12-16-11}{48})
=\dfrac{-63}{3\cdot 48}
=\dfrac{-7}{16}
$.

And so on.

I don't know of
a general expression
for the
$h_n$
that doesn't involve
nested summations.

Comment: I think you made a small mistake near the end - it should be "$n = 2$ : $h_3 = \frac{1}{3}(3g_3..."$, but other than that, this looks good. Just to make sure that I understand correctly, are you saying that $$a_n = \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m(-1)^m}{m+1} \cdot a_{n-m}$$ with $a_0 = 1$?

Comment: Good catch. Thanks. Upvoted. And yes.

Answer (score 0):

**All of this is purely formal, be my guest and make it rigorous.**

My suggestion would be the following brute force approach. However, I don't know whether this is useful for you. We can write
$$ (1+x)^{1/x} = e^{\frac{1}{x} \ln(1+x)} $$
Furthermore, we have
$$ \frac{1}{x} \ln(1+x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} x^n.$$
When we plug this into the expansion of the exponential we get using the idea of Monadologie
$$ (1+x)^{1/x} = \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{1}{k!} \left( \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} x^n \right)^k
=e \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{1}{k!} \left( \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} x^n \right)^k
= \sum_{k\geq 0} e \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{N\geq 0} \left( \sum_{1\leq \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k \ : \ \lambda_1 + \dots+ \lambda_k =N} \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{\lambda_j}}{\lambda_j+1} \right) x^N
= \sum_{N\geq 0}  (-1)^N e \left( \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{1\leq \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k \ : \ \lambda_1 + \dots+ \lambda_k =N} \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{\lambda_j+1} \right) x^N $$